# Usb drive not recongnized

Tags: usb, format

Today I inserted an usb drive in my laptop and then, it does a sound while plugged in. But, doesn't show the drive in file manager. Later that, i opened **Disks** and it showed the following.[image]

If i try to format it, it shows,
[image]

And,it freezes to 0.0%
[image]

Now,how can i get rid of that problem? 
Please suggest me something!

Comment: Change the key; nothing is eternal and electronics components fails from time to time, your key is probably broken and not usable anymore.

Comment: what does dmesg have to say?

Comment: This has happened to me before... try creating a new Partition Table with GParted. Make sure you select the correct device from the top right drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

to format the disk, firs `umount` the disk, then open it with `fdisk`, delete all the partitions and write a new partition table and reformat it. this is a really rough way to do so. but it could be helpful if you don't want the data on your disk.

'sudo umount /dev/sdx' where x is the drive (in your case '/dev/sdc'), then type 'sudo fdisk /dev/sdx' press `d` to delete (it asks you to select which partition do you want to delete, and again in your case we want to delete all, so press enter and hit `d` again till all partitions being deleted) now press `n` to make a new partition, select beginning sector (default values are good to go, so just hit `enter`) then it asks for end sector (you can type `+10G` for 10GB partition size or any thing else, again default is the end sector and it's fine for now, hit 'enter'). now you have been created a new partition on your disk, hit `w` to write changes and then exit the program, to format the disk you can use 'mkfs', i.e `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1` hit enter, when it finished, congratulation you have been formatted your disk and now it should work if the disk itself not really **dead**.
just `mount` it again or use `disks` to `format`, `mount` or any thing else you want.
i hope this would be helpful.